# JAVA SE x86 or x64?

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit

So this is probably a stupid question but I need to start working on a JAVA application and I should update my jdk I presume. So I go to the website and it has Windows x64 and x86 downloads.

My question is this. I have a 64-bit system, but my Program Files is x86. So does that mean I should use a x86 jdk or x64? I guess I am confused on why my program files folder has a different size than my system itself, or is my system x86?

I hope you can see my silly confusion on this matter.

Thank you,
-Austin

Comment: 64bit cpus HAVE to be able to execute 32bit code for backwards compatibility with 30+ years of 32bit-only software. Every 64bit windows install (amongst others) has a complete 32bit system included to run that old code. e.g. c:\windows\system32 contains the 64bit binaries for a 64bit Windows install (yea, system32, brilliant choice there, microsoft idiots), while c:\windows\syswow64 contains the 32bit binaries. You can easily have both a 32bit and a 64bit JVM install on the same system.

Comment: In general, if you are running a 64-bit OS, it doesn't really matter unless you need to take advantage of specific features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download the `x64` version since it's designed for the computer with your architecture. You have `x86` Program Files folder only for application which can't run under `64bit` environment. It's basically just backward compatibility.

Comment: ohh so the x86 is simply an architectural term for "most" 32 bit versions? Thank you!

Comment: Just Intel versions of 32bit but I believe most people use this term for all 43bit processors. Here is longer answer http://superuser.com/questions/274044/when-the-term-x86-is-used-does-it-always-refer-to-32-bit

Comment: x86 can run on 64-bit and 32-bit. x64 can only run on 64-bit.